# How to take different data types input in an array in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, uri

I am beginner and learning JavaScript. Now I am trying to solve some online judge problem with JavaScript to improve my JavaScript skill. I got stuck in a problem. In the problem, it is asking to take input `integer` and `string` form user in a row. Ex: `[10, C]` etc. How can I do that? I can take input form user of similar data types but not familiar with different data types.

Problem link: [URI 1094](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/en/problems/view/1094)

I can take input of same data types like the below code

```
var arr = readline().split(" ").map(x => parseFloat(x))
```

Now how can I take input of different data types. Ex: integer and string

Answer (score 0):

Try `var arr = readline().split(" ").map((x,i) => i==0 ? parseFloat(x) : x)`

Using the map index `i` in a condition, it can return `parseFloat(x)` when the index is zero... `x` otherwize.